# Exception: "dot" not found in path in python on mac

Tags: python, macos, path, pycaffe

I want to use `caffe.draw` to draw the caffe net by anaconda python on mac. But I got the error like this:

```
File "python/draw_net.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "python/draw_net.py", line 41, in main
    caffe.draw.draw_net_to_file(net, args.output_image_file, args.rankdir)
  File "/Users/xxh/caffe/distribute/python/caffe/draw.py", line 222, in draw_net_to_file
    fid.write(draw_net(caffe_net, rankdir, ext))
  File "/Users/xxh/caffe/distribute/python/caffe/draw.py", line 204, in draw_net
    return get_pydot_graph(caffe_net, rankdir).create(format=ext)
  File "/Users/xxh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1883, in create
    prog=prog))
Exception: "dot" not found in path.
```

I have installed pydot and graphviz ,and how can I add the dot's path to python path?

Comment: Have you installed graphviz with a package manager? `brew install graphviz`

Answer (score 30):

For me running:

```
brew install gprof2dot
```

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 25):

If you are still getting the error, I suppose you installed pydot and graphviz using pip.

Please use :

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz

pip install pydot
```

If this gives you permission issues please use:

```
sudo pip install pydot
```

This will install the complete graphviz from Ubuntu.

After this the `draw_net.py` runs correctly.

Answer (score 9):

In Mac run:

```
pip install pydot
brew install gprof2dot
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have "dot" install from source http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/CURRENT/graphviz-working.tar.gz and all works

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the methods in the above posts but unfortunately none worked for me. dot is an executable file but the problem is that it cannot be found by the system. Finally I managed to fix the problem by

1. Find the graphviz library in the system. dot should be inside the bin folder.
2. Either add the graphviz_library/bin into $PATH or create a symbolic link of dot and put it into any folder in $PATH.

Comment: I'm on same boat. How did you find where graphviz is in the system?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by installing graphviz through the command line:

```
pip install graphviz
pip install pydot
```

Answer (score -1):

In Centos7 run:

```
yum install graphviz
```