# Pydot & Graphviz setup

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I am trying to plot some a decision tree using graphviz and pydot using SKLearn in python.
From the python code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris(
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
test_idx=[0,50,100]

tree.export_graphviz(clf,
        out_file='tree.dot')#gives text file
print iris.feature_names
print iris.target_names
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/Data Structures/decision_tree_visualization.py", line 18, in <module>
    graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pydot.py", line 1691, in <lambda>
    self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pydot.py", line 1774, in write
    s = self.create(prog, format)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pydot.py", line 1883, in create
    prog=prog))
Exception: "dot" not found in path.
```

I have tried reinstalling pydot and graphviz to no avail. Any help?

Comment: I figured out how to get a visualization by running dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png in my Terminal... but I still want to figure this out.

Comment: 1) try : sudo apt-get install graphviz  2) see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243753/exception-dot-not-found-in-path-in-python-on-mac). 3) the PyGraphviz bin directory should be added to the path. 4) [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like graphviz has not been added to the system path. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path)and [this more detailed explanation](http://plantuml.com/graphviz-dot).

Not every method of installed sets the path correctly (especially pip install).