# Facing issues with Graphviz

Tags: python, pandas, macos, graphviz, dot

I have installed graphviz using the following command on my MacOS:
brew install graphviz and now it shows that my graphviz is up-to-date.

However on running the following code on my Jupyter notebook:

```
# Extract the small tree
tree_small = regressor1.estimators_[5]
# Save the tree as a png image
export_graphviz(tree_small, out_file = 'tree.dot', feature_names = home_data.columns, rounded = True, precision = 1)
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

Its throwing the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] "dot" not found in path.
> ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute 'dot', make sure the Graphviz
> executables are on your systems' PATH*

Would appreciate if someone could help me with the same.
PS: I am new to using MacOS, so I am not sure how to work with adding the dot in the PATH. I tried doing echo $PATH, it certainly doesn't include graphviz, but not sure how to check where exactly it got installed.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: "dot" not found in path in python on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243753/exception-dot-not-found-in-path-in-python-on-mac)

Comment: no. I have already tried running those commands through command line

Comment: You probably need to update `os.environ["PATH"]` to include the directory in which the `dot` command is installed.

Comment: did you google already "how to add path to PATH variable in mac" and "which in mac" (which is linux command to locate exec.)